# how to mock resultmetadata for junit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

having one function using resultmetadata.

```
    ResultSet rs // coming from some sql query.
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    if(rsmd.getColumnName(1).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("something"))
    {
    //do something here
    }
```

i have mocked resultset before, but dont know how to mock resultmetadata or put desired column name in resultset ?
i tried :

```
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = Mockito.mock(ResultSetMetaData.class);
    Mockito.when(rsmd.getColumnName(1)).thenReturn("Somwthing");
```

but it didnt worked

Comment: When you say 'didn't work', did it throw an `Exception`, or just not return the expected 'Somwthing'?

Comment: it did not return Somwthing

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your 'function using resultmetadata' after the `rsmd` variable is set, and look at the debug information for the `rsmd` there, and the one in your test class (you should be able to click further up the call stack to go into your test method) are they the same instance?

Comment: i think both are different instances, the one i am using to mock in test class shows some id, but the main method shows rsmd as null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what you need to do:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class Test {


    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {

        // prepare the dependant mock
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaMock = Mockito.mock(ResultSetMetaData.class);
        when(rsMetaMock.getColumnName(eq(1))).thenReturn("something");

        // prepare main mock for result set and define when 
        // main mock to return dependant mock
        ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
        when(rs.getMetaData()).thenReturn(rsMetaMock);

        // application logic
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        //assertions
        assertEquals(rsmd.getColumnName(1), "something");
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not able to import import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;. is there any other alternative ?

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of Mockito you are using.

Comment: Use without ArgumentMatcher: when(rsMetaMock.getColumnName(1)).thenReturn("something");